# Register generic adapters in Autofac

Tags: autofac

Is there any way to register a generic adapter in Autofac? I want to do something like

`RegisterGenericAdapter(typeof(ProcessorInvoker<>), typeof(IProcessor<>)).As(typeof(IProcessorInvoker<>))`

where `ProcessorInvoker<>` adapts from `IProcessorInvoker<>` to `IProcessor<>`.

Is there any way to achieve this in Autofac?

Answer (score 0):

[Decorators are supported on open generics](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html) but not adapters. If you're interested in that feature, [I'd recommend filing an issue to discuss how you imagine it working, after which we'd totally take a pull request](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac).